# How do I change the store of an Ext.tree.Panel in ExtJS 4.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I want to change a store of an `Ext.tree.Panel` when certain criterias are met. But somehow the documentation of ExtJS 4.1 don't shows any method to do this. I read about `reconfigure()`, but this throws a strange error (`Object [object Object] has no method indexOf`).

The Object of concern seems to be the `me.store`, while `me` is the `Ext.tree.Panel`.

Since the `Ext.tree.Panel` is my main view, I can't simply destroy and recreate it.

Comment: Does the new store have the same Model as the last one?

Comment: Gett exact error, glad you asked it on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on this really isn't clear. Reconfigure only works for grids. Try using `Ext.tree.Panel.setRootNode()`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I put Ext.tree.Panel in items of Ext.panel.Panel. And when I need to change tree use new Ext.tree.Panel.
Help function is

```
function getTreePanel(store)
{
    return new Ext.tree.Panel({
        border: false,
        bodyBorder: false,
        autoRender: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        store: store,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first set store, then set root node.

```
Ext.tree.Panel.setStore('page.SearchPage');
Ext.tree.Panel.setRootNode(NodeInterface);
```